# A windows store app containing bing map doesn't allow to create app package on ARM machine

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have developed a windows store app that consists of a bing map. I am using bing map version 1.113.601.1. It successfully allows me to create app package on x86 machine. It doesn't allow me to create app package on ARM machine. I am using the latest version of bing map from microsoft. They tell this version of bing map works well for all platforms.

Thanks
Vishnu Aravind

Comment: How do you know Bing maps prevents you from creating app package for ARM?

Comment: when tried for creation of app package it threw compile time error, saying that bing map sdk is configured to be run on x86